# error in catkin build couldn't find package "numpy_eigen"

Tags: c++, numpy, build, eigen, catkin

The first comments led me through until I reached the error below

NEW ERROR AFTER running `sudo apt install libeigen3-dev`

```
    CMake Error at rpg_emvs/mapper_emvs/CMakeLists.txt:16 (find_package):
  By not providing "FindEigen.cmake" in CMAKE_MODULE_PATH this project has
  asked CMake to find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen", but
  CMake did not find one.

  Could not find a package configuration file provided by "Eigen" with any of
  the following names:

EigenConfig.cmake
eigen-config.cmake

  Add the installation prefix of "Eigen" to CMAKE_PREFIX_PATH or set
  "Eigen_DIR" to a directory containing one of the above files.  If "Eigen"
  provides a separate development package or SDK, be sure it has been
  installed.
```

This is the Cmakelists.txt file

```
project(mapper_emvs)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8.3)

find_package(catkin_simple REQUIRED)
catkin_simple(ALL_DEPS_REQUIRED)

find_package(Eigen REQUIRED)
find_package(Boost REQUIRED system filesystem date_time thread)
#Setting include, lib directories and definitions 
include_directories(${${Boost_INCLUDE_DIR} ${EIGEN_INCLUDE_DIRS}})
```

should I try commenting the eigen add package part ?

NEW ERROR After updating CMAKE file

```
/home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/src/numpy_eigen/include/numpy_eigen/boost_python_headers.hpp:23:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

ERROR after building numpy_eigen alone

```
-- verifying file...
       file='/home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/build/eigen_catkin/eigen_src-prefix/src/3.3.4.tar.bz2'
-- MD5 hash of
    /home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/build/eigen_catkin/eigen_src-prefix/src/3.3.4.tar.bz2
  does not match expected value
    expected: 'a7aab9f758249b86c93221ad417fbe18'
      actual: 'd41d8cd98f00b204e9800998ecf8427e'
-- File already exists but hash mismatch. Removing...
-- Downloading...
   dst='/home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/build/eigen_catkin/eigen_src-prefix/src/3.3.4.tar.bz2'
   timeout='none'
-- Using src='http://bitbucket.org/eigen/eigen/get/3.3.4.tar.bz2'
[ 13%] Building CXX object numpy_eigen/CMakeFiles/numpy_eigen_test.dir/src/autogen_test_module/test_float.cpp.o
[ 13%] Building CXX object numpy_eigen/CMakeFiles/numpy_eigen_test.dir/src/autogen_test_module/numpy_eigen_test_module.cpp.o
[ 18%] Building CXX object numpy_eigen/CMakeFiles/numpy_eigen_test.dir/src/autogen_test_module/test_double.cpp.o
[ 22%] Building CXX object numpy_eigen/CMakeFiles/numpy_eigen_test.dir/src/autogen_test_module/test_uchar.cpp.o
[ 27%] Building CXX object numpy_eigen/CMakeFiles/numpy_eigen_test.dir/src/autogen_test_module/test_int.cpp.o
[ 31%] Building CXX object numpy_eigen/CMakeFiles/numpy_eigen_test.dir/src/autogen_test_module/test_long.cpp.o
/home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/src/numpy_eigen/src/autogen_test_module/test_uchar.cpp:1:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
/home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/src/numpy_eigen/src/autogen_test_module/test_float.cpp:1:22: fatal error: Eigen/Core: No such file or directory
compilation terminated.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can download and keep inside `/home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/src`(assume this is your ros workspace) folder and compile with other packages which need `numpy_eigen`.

```
cd /home/ubuntu/emvs_ws/src
git clone https://github.com/ethz-asl/numpy_eigen.git
cd ../
catkin_make
```

I guess it's better to use catkin_make instead of catkin build, something those packages getting strange errors with catkin build. Also, if this package depends on [catkin_simple](https://github.com/catkin/catkin_simple), if you don't have catkin_simple, clone that repo into src and try executing catkin_make.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion or debugging sessions; this conversation has been [archived in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220112/discussion-on-answer-by-gprathap-error-in-catkin-build-couldnt-find-package-nu).